# Zebra ZPL Commands to resize barcode to sit within a label

Tags: zebra-printers, thermal-printer, printer-control-language, zpl, zpl-ii

I am using Zebra GT800 label printer with a label role size with 2.5' * 1.75'. I'm struggling to get it resize to the label within, using ZPL commands. I tried with several values in bold text which I read in the user guide of ZPL, but no success.

When values **BY2** is used, what it happens is bar-code is getting out of the margins of the label. When I uses value **BY1** it  is too small to read though. Below with the ZPL Commands used.

```
^XA^FO150,100^**BY1**^BC,100,Y,N,N^FD00V11636000032562050^FS^XZ 

^XA^FO150,100^**BY2**^BC,100,Y,N,N^FD00V11636000032562050^FS^XZ
```

Answer (score 17):

What I would suggest is the following:

1. Continue using `^BY2` to set the module width for the barcode so
   that the scanners in question can read them.
2. For your `^BC` command, set the 6th parameter (the "mode" parameter)
   to `A` to set the mode of the Code 128 barcode to "Automatic." Doing
   this will tell the printer to analyze the data being encoded and
   will determine the best packing method. This can help automatically
   compress the printed barcode if the data is compressable (four or
   more numeric digits in a row will cause a shift to subset C which
   will help you here).

**Example:**

`^XA^FO150,100^BY2^BC,100,Y,N,N,A^FD00V11636000032562050^FS^XZ`

**Source:**

[Page 81 of this ZPL Programming Guide](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf)

Comment: @RuwanPerera you should accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: It did not worked to me http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&width=2.5&height=1.75&units=inches&index=0&zpl=%5EXA%5EFO50%2C100%5EBY2%5EBC%2C100%2CY%2CN%2CN%2CA%5EFD00V11636000000000000000032562050%5EFS%5EXZ%0A%0A%5EXA%5EFO50%2C100%5EBY2%5EBC%2C100%2CY%2CN%2CN%5EFD00V11636000032562050%5EFS%5EXZ%20%0A%0A%5EXA%5EFO150%2C100%5EBY1%5EBC%2C100%2CY%2CN%2CN%5EFD00V11636000032562050%5EFS%5EXZ%20%0A . Am I missing something ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
^XA^PRA^BY1,2^LH000,000^PQ1
^FO115,100^B3N,,075,N^FD00V11636000032562050^FS
^FO075,225^A0N,050,040^FD00V11636000032562050^FS
^XZ
```